# Setting ArcGIS field access restrictions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-10.5, postgresql-9.5

I am using ArcGIS 10.5 and creating features class in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database. But some feature classes have specific fields that some users should not edit. For example I have a "gas pipes" feature class and it has a `facility_id` column. `Admin` users can edit this field but `Viewer` users can not edit it from ArcMap. But I could not restrict the field of feature class. Or I can not hide `facility_id` field.

Is this possible?

Comment: You may be able to set permissions on each column via sql, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108860/postgresql-revoke-privileges-from-column?rq=1

Comment: ArcGIS does not support field-specific editing constraints. Even if the database does, it wouldn't be possible to enforce within a versioned editing model, since "edits" are inserts to the Adds table.

Comment: Don't remember, do Esri support editing spatial views in Postgres? Could be an option to create two views (with and without `facility_id` column) and grant different roles access to each of them respectively.